# How make a Comparator for alphabetics chars with an differrent order that the alphabetic order

Tags: java, char, comparator

My problem is that I want to compare some character not using the alphabetic sort. 
Here is my order relation : A < B < T < Q < C < D < E < F ...

How can I create a Comparator for this? Must I write all the cases like this:

```
if (char1.equals(char2)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (char1.equals("A")) {
            return -1;
        } else if (char1.equals("B") && char2.equals("A")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (char1.equals("T")
                && (char2.equals("B") || char2.equals("A"))) {
            return 1;
        } else if (char1.equals("Q")
                && (char2.equals("T") || char2.equals("B") || char2
                        .equals("A"))) {
            return 1;
        } else if (char1.equals("C")
                && (char2.equals("Q") || char2.equals("T")
                        || char2.equals("B") || char2.equals("A"))) {
            return 1;
        } else if (char1.equals("D")
                && (char2.equals("C") || char2.equals("Q")
                        || char2.equals("T") || char2.equals("B") || char2
                            .equals("A"))) {
            return 1;
        } else if (char1.equals("E")
                && (char2.equals("D") || char2.equals("C")
                        || char2.equals("Q") || char2.equals("T")
                        || char2.equals("B") || char2.equals("A"))) {
            return 1;
        } else if (char1.equals("F")
                && (char2.equals("E") || char2.equals("D")
                        || char2.equals("C") || char2.equals("Q")
                        || char2.equals("T") || char2.equals("B") || char2
                            .equals("A"))) {
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use an enum instead of a character? As I understand, you only want to compare single characres, not strings.

Comment: Create a lookup table (char -> order) and compare `lookup[char1]` to `lookup[char2]`.

Comment: One solution would be to put the char in a list and use the indexes

Comment: First I created a lookup table but my project manager don't want it

Comment: @T.Sutter Surely your project manager should be telling you what he *does* want, then?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to compare Strings using your custom character ordering, create a [`RuleBasedCollator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html), e.g.

```
String myRules = "< a, A < b, B < t, T < q, Q < c, C < d, D < e, E < f, F < g, G" +
                 "< h, H < i, I < j, J < k, K < l, L < m, M < n, N < o, O < p, P" +
                 "< r, R < s, S < u, U < v, V < w, W < x, X < y, Y < z, Z";
RuleBasedCollator myCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(myRules);

String[] test = { "a", "B", "c", "D", "q", "T", "cc", "cB", "cq", "cT" };
Arrays.sort(test, myCollator);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
```

*Output*

```
[a, B, T, q, c, cB, cT, cq, cc, D]
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the characters in the order you want in an array char[] or list (List)

Compare based on the index of the character in the list/array

`list.indexOf(char1) - list.indexOf(char2);`

Comment: If performance matters, don't use a `LinkedList`. Use an `ArrayList` or even better a `HashMap`.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Why do you think `ArrayList` is faster than `LinkedList` for a sequential search of the list using [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)?

Comment: @Andreas: Because it most probably makes better use of the hardware memory cache.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy solution:

First put your chars in a List:

```
char[] arrayChars= {'A','B','T', ... };
 List<Character> sortedChars= new ArrayList<Character>();
for (char c : arrayChars) { // Arrays.asList won't work
    sortedChars.add(c);
}
```

And then compare the indexes:

```
int compare(char a,char b) {
  return sortedChars.indexOf(a) - sortedChars.indexOf(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's look so easy

Comment: indexOf is not available on a char[]. I have to use a List

Comment: Oops, you're right, fixed

Comment: That's work fine. I finished the code yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<Character> reference = new ArrayList<Character>(
              Arrays.asList(new Character[] {'A','B','T','Q','C','D','E','F'}));

        Character[] toBeSorted = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','Q','T'};

        Comparator<Character> myComparator = new Comparator<Character>() {

            public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
                Integer i1 = reference.indexOf(o1);
                Integer i2 = reference.indexOf(o2);
                return i1.compareTo(i2);
            }

        };

        Arrays.sort(toBeSorted, myComparator);

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(toBeSorted));

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

the integers (N) carry a what is called a natural order. So you simply put your stuff in a list indexed by integers, following the order you want to implement. Then when the time comes to compare 2 chars, you compare their indexes and that's it !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use String but it works fine with that :

```
public class IndiceRepetitionComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    List<String> relationOrdre = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "T", "Q", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
            "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");

    @Override
    public int compare(String indiceRepetition1, String indiceRepetition2) {

        // même objet
        if (indiceRepetition1 == indiceRepetition2) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (indiceRepetition1 == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (indiceRepetition2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        return (relationOrdre.indexOf(indiceRepetition1) - relationOrdre.indexOf(indiceRepetition2) > 0) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help